# R optim not running all iterations. Results change if I call it multiple times

Tags: r, optimization, optim

I am using `optim` to solve an optimization problem. It is a standard minimization of L2 norm, so it is positive, well behaved. However, when using optim, I run into some issues. First I call

```
> lambda2
$par
[1]  4.6105840762  0.1268444008 -0.8488319926 -0.1734999439 -0.8090172550 -0.0006518246

$value
[1] 0.004230469

$counts
function gradient 
    1317       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Which seems fine. However, `lambda2$value` is still large. If I run another iteration, using `lambda2$par`, I get a better result. As you can see from the results, the number of iterations has not reached `maxit` and the tolerance is still above the desired one. My tolerance is really low, pretty much unreachable, but I would like to run more iterations.

Here is the outcome if I call the function again

```
> lambda2=optim(lambda2$par,fn,control = list(maxit=100000,abstol=10e-08))
> lambda2
$par
[1]  3.8098969475  0.1892906218 -1.4387655921 -0.3345618667 -1.2719792359 -0.0000129872

$value
[1] 0.001079045

$counts
function gradient 
    1529       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

I found the following question, but the suggested solution only work for one method of optim, therefore I was not able to apply it to my problem.
[How can I force r optim to run more iterations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851794/how-can-i-force-r-optim-to-run-more-iterations)

Comment: Maybe adjust `reltol`? Setting `trace = 1` should already give some useful information. You might want to create profile plots for the fit.

Comment: How do we know " the tolerance is still above the desired one" ? The output from `optim()` only shows the achieved value of the objective function, not the achieved (relative or absolute) tolerance.  Did you set `abstol` in the `control=` argument?  Have you considered using `method = "BFGS"` instead of the default Nelder-Mead?  Can you supply a gradient function?

Comment: @BenBolker I did set `abstol=10e-8.` I did consider using `"BFGS"`, but it takes longer and the results are not better. Finally, it is possible to find a gradient function, however I did not supply it. I solved the same problem years ago with MATLAB's `fmincon` and it worked without gradient.

Comment: In my limited experience, Matlab's optimization functions are uncannily good (my  working theory is that since Matlab is commercial/has to satisfy customers, they have put enormous efforts into tuning and improving their optimization algorithms). If you can give a *minimal* example we might be able to give some more guidance. What happens if you set `abstol` even lower?  Maybe try the Nelder-Mead or BOBYQA algorithms from the `nloptr` package?